# No shipping costs for some categories

Tags: magento-1, upgrade, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping

I want to stop my webshop from calculating shipping costs for entire categorie outlet: https://sportinngerritsen.nl/outlet.

I made a shopping cart price rule for this (see the pictures below), but it's not working. What am I doing wrong? I recently updated from 1.6.1 to 1.9.2.1 and it did work before the update.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem where the 'is one of' did not work correctly, or at least not as expected.

You could try to specify all of the categories by themselves and changing the 'All' in the rule above to 'Any'.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve it:
If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ANY  of these conditions true: 
Category  is  93  
Category  is  94  
Category  is  95  
Category  is  97  
Category  is  99  
Category  is  98  
Category  is  96